# Insert multiple label fields using for loop in a form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using jquery ajax in codeigniter framework to load a pop up modal on button click. I pass ajax request to a function in controller and receive some data which should be shown in my pop up modal.  Number of labels of the modal is depend on the size of the array received by the ajax request.

I have no idea how to do this. But I tried of passing the size of the received array to a hidden type input field in form created on the pop up modal.

Following is my javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

   $(document).on('click','#btn_more', function() {
    empId = $('#employeeId').html();
    fiter_employees(empId);
   });

    function fiter_employees(empId){

    var empSet ={
      empId: empId,
      method: 'ajax'
    };

    var empSentUrl = 'http://localhost/eventmanagementsystem/index.php/employee/get_emp_positions';

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: empSentUrl,
      data: empSet,

      success: function(data){

      $('#modal_pkg1').html(data.empPosition.length)

       $('#employeePositions').modal();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

In my pop up model I used the following codes which is not succeeded.

```
<div id="employeePositions" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">

  <div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Name :</h4><br/>

   <form>
  <?php
  for ($i=0; $i < ?>
  <input type="hidden" id="modal_pkg1" value="modal_pkg1" /> 
  <?php
  ; $i++) { ?>
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="event_name"></h4> 
  <?php
  } ?>
  </form>
```

Can someone tell me the correct me of doing this please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code has executed the moment you load the page, so when you change the  `modal_pkg1` value, nothing will happen.
Also, the foor loop itself will not work on load, as it's expecting a number that is not there.

I suggest you do it fully in JS, remove all php code from your script; something like below :

in your Ajax success function :

```
.success(function(data){
     var htmlStr = ''  
     for(var i=0;i<data.empPosition.length;i++){
         htmlStr+='<whatever html element you want to display>'
     }
     $('form').html(htmlStr) // add the generated html string to the <form> element
     $('#employeePositions').modal();
}
```

Comment: THANK U for your quick responce.